# Is it possible to fetch only a specific branch of a Hierarchy using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Let us say I have a Hierarchy for the different parts of car companies.

For eg

```
1. Audi
    1.1 Engine
            1.1.1 Piston
            1.1.2 Crankshaft
    1.2 Transmission
            1.2.1 Gears
            1.2.2 Shift

2. Ferrari
    2.1 Engine
            2.1.1 Piston
            2.1.2 Crankshaft
    2.2 Transmission
            2.2.1 Gears
            2.2.2 Shift
    

3. Ford
    3.1 Engine
            3.1.1 Piston
            3.1.2 Crankshaft
    3.2 Transmission
            3.2.1 Gears
```

Now the output must contain only the Hierarchy which has "Shift" in it. The rest must not be seen in my output. The output should look as below :

1. Audi
   1.2 Transmission
   1.2.2 Shift
2. Ferrari
   2.2 Transmission
   2.2.2 Shift

Is there any specific element that I can use to get this output?

Updating a sample XML input file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Hierarchy>
    <Board>
        <Name>Audi</Name>
        <Id>ABCDE</Id>
        <ParentId></ParentId>
        <General>
            <Name>Audi</Name>
            <Description>Car brand</Description>
            <Template>LEVEL1</Template>
        </General>
    </Board>
    <Board>
        <Name>Engine</Name>
        <Id>EFGHI</Id>
        <ParentId>ABCDE</ParentId>
        <General>
            <Name>Engine</Name>
            <Description>Part of Car</Description>
            <Template>LEVEL2</Template>
        </General>
    </Board>
    <Board>
        <Name>Piston</Name>
        <Id>JKLMN</Id>
        <ParentId>EFGHI</ParentId>
        <General>
            <Name>Department_Heads</Name>
            <Description>Part of Engine</Description>
            <Template>LEVEL3</Template>
        </General>
    </Board>
    <Board>
        <Name>Crankshaft</Name>
        <Id>OPQRS</Id>
        <ParentId>EFGHI</ParentId>
        <General>
            <Name>Department_Heads</Name>
            <Description>Part of Engine</Description>
            <Template>LEVEL3</Template>
        </General>
    </Board>
    <Board>
        <Name>Transmission</Name>
        <Id>TUVWX</Id>
        <ParentId>ABCDE</ParentId>
        <General>
            <Name>Transmission</Name>
            <Description>Part of Car</Description>
            <Template>LEVEL2</Template>
        </General>
    </Board>
    <Board>
        <Name>Gear</Name>
        <Id>CSDKL</Id>
        <ParentId>TUVWX</ParentId>
        <General>
            <Name>Gear</Name>
            <Description>Part of Transmission</Description>
            <Template>LEVEL3</Template>
        </General>
    </Board>
    <Board>
        <Name>Shift</Name>
        <Id>SDKLFH</Id>
        <ParentId>TUVWX</ParentId>
        <General>
            <Name>Shift</Name>
            <Description>Part of Transmission</Description>
            <Template>LEVEL3</Template>
        </General>
    </Board>
</Hierarchy>
```

The XSLT approach that i take is this :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Hierarchy>
            <xsl:for-each select="Hierarchy/Board">

                <xsl:if test="General/Template='LEVEL1'">
                    <xsl:variable name="blabla" select="Id"/>
                    <Board>
                        
                        <Name>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
                        </Name>
                        <Template>CAR1</Template>
                        <Description>
                            <xsl:value-of select = "General/Description"/>
                        </Description>
                        <xsl:for-each select="//Board">
                            <xsl:if test="ParentId = $blabla">
                            
                                <Board>
                                    <xsl:variable name="blablablablabla" select="Id"/>
                                    
                                    <Name>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
                                    </Name>
                                    <Template>TRANSMISSION</Template>
                                    <Description>
                                        <xsl:value-of select = "General/Description"/>
                                    </Description>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="//Board">
                                        <xsl:if test="ParentId = $blablablablabla">
                                        
                                            <Board>
                                                <xsl:variable name="blablablablablablablablablablablabla" select="Id"/>
                                                
                                                <Name>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
                                                </Name>
                                                <Template>SHIFT</Template>
                                                <Description>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select = "General/Description"/>
                                                </Description>
                                            </Board>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </Board>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        
                    </Board>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
                      
        </Hierarchy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please note that I have just mentioned only a specific part of the whole XSLT. Usually when i use this it works fine, but when the data increases, like 5 lakh elements like above, and when the "Shift" is at different levels(here it is at level 3 in the Hierarchy tree) , for some reason it creates duplicates and also elements without any template in it. I just want to know if there is any other approach.

The output XML sample is also mentioned below :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Hierarchy>
      <Board>
        <Name>Audi</Name>
        <Template>LEVEL1</Template>
        <Description>Car brand</Description>
         <Board>
          <Name>Transmission</Name>
          <Template>LEVEL2</Template>
          <Description>Part of Car</Description>
           <Board>
           <Name>Shift</Name>
           <Template>LEVEL3</Template>
            <Description>Part of Transmission</Description>
          
          </Board>
        </Board>

   </Board>
   <Board>
        <Name>Ferrari</Name>
        <Template>LEVEL1</Template>
        <Description>Car brand</Description>
         <Board>
          <Name>Transmission</Name>
          <Template>LEVEL2</Template>
          <Description>Part of Car</Description>
           <Board>
           <Name>Shift</Name>
           <Template>LEVEL3</Template>
            <Description>Part of Transmission</Description>
          
          </Board>
        </Board>

   </Board>
</Hierarchy>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] showing a sample input (as XML code), the expected output (also as code) and your current attempt. -- Hint: this is rather trivial if you only pass nodes that have "Shift" on the `descendant-or-self` axis.

Comment: I like this question.  Essentially, you want to find a node with a specifed data value.  Then you want to get that node, and all of it's ancestors (ie parent, grandparent, great grand parent ect.)  So, here's one approach:  Find the specified data point.  Create a node-set using the ancestor-or-self axis, then output the node-set in the correct order...  If you need more help, please modify you question as Michael suggested above...

Comment: @Bluewood66 Your approach will create duplicate branches for sibling nodes.

Comment: @michael.hor257k    If, for example, I find the "1.2.2 Shift" node, then get it's parent node "1.2 Transmission", then get it's grandparent "1. Audi".  That would work.  Likewise, If get "2.2.2 Shift" then parent "2.2 Transmission" the grandparent "2. Ferrari" that would also work.  So, as long as I'm starting with the child node with "Shift" in it, I'm probably good.  The approach is bottom up, rather than top down...  But, please let me know how duplicate branches are created.  I think there would be more problem with a top down approach.

Comment: @Bluewood66 I will clarify this when OP posts his XML code - but consider what will happen if a manufacturer has two divisions. And what would be your result's root element.

Comment: @Bluewood66 : I have updated the xml file above. Please note that I have not provided the whole file because it is too large , but a part of the Hierarchy(Audi). Sincere apologies for the delay in response and please let me know if any further information is required.

Comment: @michael.hor257k

Comment: Good. Now you only need to add the expected output (also as code) and your current attempt.

Comment: @Bluewood66 : I have updated the xslt and expected output as well.

Comment: @michael.hor257k : I have updated the xslt and expected output as well.

Comment: The new examples are ambiguous. Please post an example where more than one branch satisfies the condition (like your original non-XML example).

Comment: @michael.hor257k How is it ambigious? I am getting output using the method. But like i mentioned, since i can only show only a small part of the whole Hierarchy, it is easy. But when there are more than 1 lakh elements, where the match is not done based on the names of the element but another attribute, it gets complicated. I have updated once again.

Comment: It is ambiguous because I don't know what the output should look like. Should it have a separate tree for each "fruit" (as suggested by @Bluewood66) or should it prune the tree leaving only fruit-bearing branches.

Comment: Hi @OnlyforSurfing, I just updated my answer based on your new requirement.  This should give  you some ideas at least.

Comment: @michael.hor257k : It should prune the tree leaving only fruit bearing branches. I will also try Bluewood's method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment to your question I said this is rather trivial. That is because I thought your input XML had a hierarchical structure. As it turns out, the hierarchy needs to be derived by tracing the cross-references from each Board to its parent.

This means the transformation needs to take place in two passes: first, build a proper hierarchical tree; then prune this tree to leave only fruit-bearing branches.

**XSLT 1.0 (+ EXSLT node-set function)**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="children" match="Board" use="ParentId" />

<xsl:template match="/Hierarchy">
    <!-- first pass -->
    <xsl:variable name="tree">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Board[General/Template='LEVEL1']" mode="first-pass"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- output -->
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($tree)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Board" mode="first-pass">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('children', Id)" mode="first-pass"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Board">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="General/*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Board[descendant-or-self::Board/Name='Shift']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the provided input XML, this will produce:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Hierarchy>
  <Board>
    <Name>Audi</Name>
    <Description>Car brand</Description>
    <Template>LEVEL1</Template>
    <Board>
      <Name>Transmission</Name>
      <Description>Part of Car</Description>
      <Template>LEVEL2</Template>
      <Board>
        <Name>Shift</Name>
        <Description>Part of Transmission</Description>
        <Template>LEVEL3</Template>
      </Board>
    </Board>
  </Board>
</Hierarchy>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Onlyfor Surfing try adding this code to you stylesheet.  You can smooth it out as you see fit.

```
<xsl:key name="myKey" match="Board" use="Id"/>

<xsl:variable name="root" select="/"/>

<!-- I would suggest working out the hierarchy first as follows: -->
<xsl:variable name="metadata">
  <!-- Change the Board filter to be whatever level 3 starting nodes that you want. 
       You could just use level 3, if you want.  Or an attribute.
    -->
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//Board[contains(Name, 'Shift') or contains(Name, 'Gear')]" mode="metadata"/> 
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="metadataList" select="msxml:node-set($metadata)"/>

<xsl:template match="Hierarchy">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each select="$metadataList/element">
      <xsl:variable name="position" select="position()"/>
      <xsl:variable name="firstId" select="Id[1]"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="$root">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('myKey', $firstId)">
          <xsl:with-param name="Id" select="$firstId"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="position" select="$position"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Board">
  <xsl:param name="Id"/>
  <xsl:param name="position"/>
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Name"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="General/Template"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="General/Description"/>
    <xsl:variable name="followingId" select="$metadataList/element[number($position)]/Id[. = $Id]/following-sibling::Id[1]"/>
    <xsl:if test="$followingId != ''">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('myKey', $followingId)">
        <xsl:with-param name="Id" select="$followingId"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="position" select="$position"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
 
<xsl:template match="Name">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Template">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Description">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>


<!-- metadata mode -->
<xsl:template match="Board" mode="metadata">
  <xsl:element name="element">
    <xsl:if test="ParentId != ''">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('myKey', ParentId)" mode="metadata2">
        <xsl:with-param name="ParId" select="ParentId"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:element name="Id">
      <xsl:value-of select="Id"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!-- metadata2 mode -->
<xsl:template match="Board" mode="metadata2">
  <xsl:if test="ParentId != ''">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('myKey', ParentId)" mode="metadata2">
      <xsl:with-param name="ParId" select="ParentId"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:element name="Id">
    <xsl:value-of select="Id"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Iterate thru all node.  -->
<xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</xsl:template>
```